# How to make a phone call through programming

Tags: ios, iphone

How to make a phone call through programming in iOS?

Answer (score 3):

Use UIApplication:openURL method to open a resource from other program. This includes opening mail, phone number, google maps search etc..

So, in order for you to call somebody using the method, you can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456789"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the tel:// URL to specify a phone number just like you would specify a web-page with http://

This makes it easy to transition from a web interface to a phone style voice interface. The format also theoretically supports alternative SIP providers and extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> tel:1-408-555-5555

More at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html