# How can i make phone calls from my application?

Tags: iphone

i want to make an application which makes phone calls.i am new in this field.Please give some guide lines.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985872/how-to-make-a-phone-call-through-programming

Answer (score 1):

The URL scheme format (according to the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1)) is tel: NOT tel://.  While the latter works now, it is not consistent with Apple's documentation and may not work in the future.  Aside from that detail, Noah's and mihirpmehta's suggestions are the correct way to initiate a phone call from within your app.  Keep in mind though, that your app will quit when the phone app is launched so you may want to save state before opening the URL.

Answer (score 0):

use

[[UIApplication application] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8005551212"]];

It will only work in iphone... not in simulator...

Answer (score 0):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://5558675309"]]`